# How can I make express return JSON after res.render EJS template?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, ejs

I need to render a page and send json response express restful api.
I was able to do one thing, or the other, not both. 
Here's what I have:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('myDatabase').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('mytemplate.ejs', {myDatabase: result})
  })
})
```

The code above renders the template correctly but doesn't return any JSON response.

However, to render and have a 200 response I tried:

[image: what I tried]

Here is what is returning:

> {
>       "htmlContent": {},
>       "status": "200"
>   }

This means it's returning json but not the ejs template myTemplate.ejs

Comment: What is purpose of it?

Comment: @Sanjiv Render myTemplate.ejs and return a status 200 for the restful API

Comment: You need htmlContent inside `{ "htmlContent": #{some_ejs_content}, "status": "200" }` . Am i right? @staminna

Comment: res.render render the view and send the rendered HTML content directly to the client.

Comment: content type is app/json no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I have updated my answer to check Accept header. Browser does not send application/json so the code gives html, for your api calls you send `Accept: application/json` then it gives json back

```
let ejs = require('ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('myDatabase').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

       if(req.header('Accept').includes('application/json')){
        res.send(result);
       }else{
        res.render('mytemplate.ejs', {myDatabase: result});
       }
  })
})
```

Comment: What should I put in str? It's printing the HTML values in JSON format and not HTML markup and JSON format like status:200

Comment: in str you get the rendered HTML

Comment: I only get foo: "bar" // additional data you want to send

Comment: did you check for `err` maybe you are getting an error while rendering

Comment: I don't get any err though the browser instead rendering the content as HTML, shows up a JSON file with {"html":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <title>MY APP</title>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\">\n</head>\n<body>\n    <h1>User signin</h1>\n    <div>\n    <ul class=\"users\">\n        \n            <li class=\"users\">\

Comment: Isn't that what you asked in the question?

Comment: I mean if it was possible to have the same route render HTML in browser and JSON to backend API

Comment: Understood your problem, I have updated my answer to check Accept header. Browser does not send application/json so the code gives html, for your api calls you send Accept: application/json then it gives json back